# Não consigo passar um valor para uma variável

Tags: angular

Porque no console.log(x) o terminal me mostra o array e no console.log("Categories: " + this.categories) ele me mostra undefined?

```
buildCategories() {

    const teste = this.categoriesService.read();

    teste.subscribe(x => {
        this.categories = x;
        console.log(x);
    }
        );

    console.log("Categories: " + this.categories);

}
```

Comment: Ele imprime o **x** no primeiro log, pq vc está imprimindo exatamente o x. Já no segundo log vc esta imprimindo uma variável que **teoricamente** possui o x como valor.

Comment: Mas eu atribuí o valor de x à variável categories ou eu fiz errado?

Comment: X é um array certo? A variável categories, é do tipo array??!

Answer (score 3):

Esse erro tem a ver que os subscribe serem async logo ele nao fica parado nele entao o console.log que esta fora do subscrive quando e executado ainda nao tem value a var